How to Implement Real-Time Inventory Tracking in IoT-Enabled Vending Machines?
The primary goal of this question is to gather insights and solutions for implementing IoT-based real-time inventory tracking in vending machines. The challenges outlined address key aspects of the project, such as sensor selection, data transmission, system integration, data security, and cost-effectiveness. By providing detailed project objectives and specific challenges, the question seeks to engage the Stack Overflow community in providing practical advice, best practices, and examples from their experiences
What I Have Tried:

Sensor Selection: Researched and shortlisted a few sensors (e.g., load cells, infrared sensors) that can accurately monitor inventory levels.
Connectivity Options: Considered using Wi-Fi and cellular networks for data transmission. Tested initial setups but faced intermittent connectivity issues.
Data Processing: Set up a basic cloud infrastructure using AWS IoT Core to collect and process data from the sensors.
Prototype: Built a basic prototype with an Arduino board and a load cell to measure stock levels and send data to AWS IoT Core. The prototype works, but the accuracy and reliability need improvement.

What I Am Expecting:

Recommendations on the best type of sensors for accurate and reliable inventory tracking.
Solutions for ensuring stable data transmission in areas with poor connectivity.
Tips on power management for IoT devices in vending machines.
Advice on integrating the new IoT components with our existing backend system.


This is way too broad for Stack Overflow, which is about answering specific programming questions.
